# UITableViewCell Opacity not detected on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if ([indexPath row] %2 == 0)
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = kColorTablePrimary;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = kColorTableSecondary;
    }
}
```

This is the code I am currently using, the opacity is only being detected on iPhone but I have a breakpoint in this code and it's definitely being called when I use the iPad just the opacity isn't showing. I've been through the setup and the cells are both setup identically, the same with the UITableViews.

Below are screenshots of the differences in appearance:

[image: iPhone]
[image: iPad]

Comment: Check this [issue posted on Apple's forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5367716)

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure if this applies as I am showing both results on the simulator which I presumed would work as if run on the latest devices? And shouldn't take in to account these settings?